# String matches() not able to pick ^

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to do an regex expression evaluation using java.

^ - Should match everything that starts with it Example: ^begin (This means it should match everything that start with begin)

Below is the Java on the same

```
public class RgexTEst {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String a = "888111231";
    String rgex = "8881";
        System.out.println(a.matches("^"+(rgex)));


    }
}
```

Here I am trying to match those which start with "8881" but it is resulting in false.

I already have the answer using .* and startWith(). I want to know how it can be done using ^

Comment: You need `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew did not know it was already there